# Streaming audio/video by Socket from pc to android

Tags: android, google-chrome, sockets, video, stream

I recently try to stream camera video from pc to smartphone android-6 and viceversa using this project : https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC.
that have a node server and a browser client.

and for the client(smartphone): https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC.

The problem is that:
If I stream via socket from pc(firefox) to android everything is alright.
If I stream from pc(chrome) to another pc(chrome) everything is alright.
If I stream from pc(chrome) to another pc(firefox) and viceversa everything is alright.

But if I stream from pc(chrome) to smartphone android i have one problem:
the pc client receive the smartphone video correctly, but my smartphone receive audio correctly and video only for first two seconds.

i haven't error, no log problems. both the android app and server application keep working well but the opengl surface that have to show the remote stream stuck.

any tips?
thank you.